# How to solve the MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I have the next error (the picture) when i try to connect a database with Visual Studio.

My code is:
class CConnection
{
MySqlConnection conex = new MySqlConnection();

```
    static string servidor = "localhost";
    static string bd = "sakila";
    static string usuario = "root";
    static string pass = "root123";
    static string puerto = "3306";

    string cadenaConexion = "server=" + servidor + ";" + "port=" + 
        puerto + ";" + "user id=" + usuario + ";" + "password=" + pass + ":" + "database=" + bd + ";";

    public MySqlConnection establecerConex() {
        try{
            conex.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion;
            conex.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Se logro la conexion.");
        }
        catch(MySqlException e) {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo establcer la conexion, error: " + e.ToString());
        }
        return conex;
    }
```

Please, help me with this.

I try to connect a database with Visual Studio and give me error.

mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlexception (0x80004005) 'authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'catching_sha2_password'.

Comment: Don't hardcode the connection string like that. This looks like an authentication problem, are you trying to connect to an instance of MySQL running on the localhost?